Hi! I am a rookie developer on training... I have a problem with the set up environment, installing dependencies and running basic commands
thanks for your time.
I will try to formulate my question since I don't even know what I don't know haha...
I am a newbie, starting the developer journey on my own... I am doing Codecademy full stack course.. for some reason my VScode when I download the project folders they send for certain exercises(now is React), and I try running my basic environment set up: like installing node modules, then npm start to get my development server running, but even before installing my React-Routes the terminal is showing me errors. such as:
**
(node:27092) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit**
but it fills the terminal with these listeners and memory leak.
I was thinking about uninstalling my VScode and installing it again, and even delete all the "junk" projects I have been making for educational purposes. Since I don't know If making so many local repositories and packages installed are messing with my computer?
again, I am a rookie haha... but If anyone has any idea or just general recommendations on setting up, or the EventEmmitter memory leak issue fix...
Thanks and hope you all are well!
Happy Coding haha
Well I tried downloading the compressed files multiple times, and creating new folders each time, I also used commands to uninstall dependencies and re-install them, I used commands to clean the cache.. Could it be that since the code in the components is not yet completed, it is causing the event problem?
